# Remove duplicates when calling from Github API in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, github-api

I have a function where I am calling the list of Filetypes from the gist API of a user by looping through it (https://api.github.com/users/getify/gists) :

```
const FileTags = ({files}) => {
  return(
    <div>
      {
          Object.keys(files).map(function (key) {
            return(
              <ul>
              <li> {files[key].language } </li>
            </ul>
            )
          })
        }
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am able to successfully call the list of languages but the list is with a lot of duplicates, for example:

Markdown
Markdown
JavaScript
JavaScript
JavaScript
JavaScript
JavaScript

How do I filter out unique languages without them repeating such as 
"Markdown Javascript"
?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
const FileTags = ( {files } ) =>
    <div>
      <ul>
      {
          [...new Set(Object.keys(files).map(key => files[key].language))]
            .map( el => <li>{el}</li>)
      }
      </ul>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether
>   primitive values or object references.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a difference. i tried this and I still get duplicate values

Comment: Isn't your files variable is an object of objects? Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/n8v95l5xj If your conditions are different you can change the code according to that. But, at the end you should get unique values somehow.

Comment: I tried in my project and it didn't work :(
When I use https://api.github.com/users/getify/gists, he has multiple language and all the duplicates appear. The code works in my Filetag however in my main page where I render out the data, if I change the parameters I get an error. Currently how I call it is:


{
                users.map((user, i) => {
                  return <FileTags
                  files={users[i].files}
                  />
                })
            }


is it perhaps something to do with here? Apologies I am new to React

Comment: No need to apologize but it would be better to add other parts of your code. You can even use codesanbox if it is not a problem. But for the sake of quality of your question, adding related code parts is more important. Codesandbox is optional. I'm off to go sleeping but this will help others who wants to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If you are still up here is my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/x7n4korjpo

When you search for "getify" in index.js, you can see the middle column where I am facing the issue

Comment: Ok. You are fetching a user's gists here, not actually users. You have a bunch of gist information (all the objects) and there is a "files" object holds some information about those gists. There are *.md files and there is the language information. My code actually works but for only one gist. If you carefully look the page there are multiple ul's. This is because you are mapping all the gists. For each gist my suggestion works, in each "ul" we are cleaning the duplicates. But since we don't do this for other gist objects, you see duplicates in other ul's.

Comment: You have some options here. You can somehow extract and merge all the "files"  before sending FileTags (no map). Or after mapping and passing to FileTags, you can merge and remove duplicates there.